# How to be more verbose on tests?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I wanted to have more verbose output for each test step;
Any ideas on how could I best achieve this without adding console.log after each step ?

I tried to overload the `t` object as shown below but can't get to have it work more than one time in the output.

in mylib.js

```
exports.init = function(t) {
    t.oTypeText = t.typeText;

    t.typeText = function fn(selector, data, opts) {
        console.log('typing text in '+selector+': '+data);
        return t.oTypeText(selector, data, opts);
    };

    return;
};
```

in test.js

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
const mylib = require('./mylib');


fixture("Getting Started")
    .page("https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example");


test('My first test', async t => {
    mylib.init(t);
    await t.typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
           .selectText('#developer-name').pressKey('delete')
           .typeText('#developer-name', 'new name')
           .selectText('#developer-name').pressKey('delete')
           .typeText('#developer-name', 'another name');
    await t.click('#submit-button');

});
```

result is:

```
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
 Running tests in:
 - Firefox 68.0.0 / Mac OS X 10.14.0

 Getting Started
(node:62978) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
typing text in #developer-name: John Smith
 ✓ My first test


 1 passed (4s)
```

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe doesn't support this feature out of box. I've created suggestion for you use case - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4001 in the TestCafe repository. We can use the way with action overriding right now, but theoretically it can broke some functionality.